# How to get rid of the default single quotes in parameterized queries in clickhouse

Tags: prepared-statement, clickhouse

Consider this simple program:

```py
from clickhouse_driver import Client

c = Client(host="localhost")
params = {"database": "test", "table": "t"}
query = c.substitute_params( query='SELECT * from %(database)s.%(table)s', params= params, context=c.connection.context)
print(query)
```

Clickhouse will put single quotes around the parameters, so the query result will be:

```
SELECT * from 'test'.'t'
```

I could also use f-string and the problem will be solved but that's vulnerable to SQLI. If I understand correctly, this is how parameterized queries are used in clickhouse to prevent SQLI.
How can we prevent the quotes from being put around the parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand it, substitute_params is not intended for database object identifiers like database and table, since those have to be quoted "differently" in ClickHouse (generally with backticks) than actual literal string values (with single quotes).  https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/sql-reference/syntax/#identifiers

In general you can do your own bit of "SQL Injection defense" by validating the inputs for database and table, like ensuring they match a simple regex like "are all lower case letters or underscore" that applies to your ClickHouse schema.  In that case using an f-string should be safe.

ClickHouse also support "server side substitution" where you can use an `Identifier` type for this use case, but I don't believe that feature is available in clickhouse-driver.

Comment: this is not limited to substitute_params, the same problem arises when using client.execute() and then passing the parameters to params argument in the function. In that case, the program just crashes because clickhouse does not understand that syntax: DB::Exception: Syntax error: failed at position 15 (''test''): 'test'.'t'.

Comment: But I mean, why does clickhouse put the single quotes around the parameterized thing anyway? That is just so unpractical and does not add anything.

Comment: I think client.execute() calls substitute_parameters under the covers.  The intent is to substitute for column values in the core SQL query, like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = %(param_1)s`, where you need single quotes around a String parameter value.